# EXCEL VBA - Assigning class instance to dynamic array

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic-arrays

I am instantiating an object every time I loop through a row and store a data in that row into that object. I am appending them to an array, but I get'Object Variable or With Block variable not set" error. I also tried `Set Headers(Counter) = objRow`, but then all the element of the array becomes the same as the last element of the array.

Could anybody point out what is wrong with my code below??

Thank you so much in advance.

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 0
Public Headers() As clsDataRow

Sub CreateTemplate()

Dim iLastRow As Integer
Dim iHeaderCount As Integer
Dim rngFirstRow As Range
Dim Counter As Integer
Set rngFirstRow = shtSetup.Range("rngTemplate")


With shtSetup

    'Get the last row of the table
    iLastRow = .Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    'Get the number of headers
    iHeaderCount = iLastRow - rngFirstRow.Row + 1
    'Initialize the public static variable array to store DataRow class instances
    ReDim Headers(iHeaderCount - 1)

    'For each row, we create clsDataRow instance with relevant data
    For Counter = 0 To iHeaderCount - 1

        Dim objRow As New clsDataRow
        objRow.Name = rngFirstRow.Offset(Counter, 0).Value
        objRow.Number = rngFirstRow.Offset(Counter, 1).Value
        objRow.PDFFieldName = rngFirstRow.Offset(Counter, 2).Value
        objRow.MinCharLimit = rngFirstRow.Offset(Counter, 3).Value
        objRow.MaxCharLimit = rngFirstRow.Offset(Counter, 4).Value
        Headers(Counter) = objRow 'THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR HAPPENS

    Next


   End With


End Sub
```

Comment: Please share also the definition of `clsDataRow`. Also, what is the value of `Counter` when you get the error?

Comment: Hi Thanks for the response! `clsDataRow` definition only has the class properties like Name Number and etc. Counter is 0 when I get the error.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea to declare variables within a loop, and this is an example of why.  In this case, you don't need a new variable for every iteration of the loop anyhow - you could just re-use the same one repeatedly since `ObjRow` doesn't need to exist outside of the loop.

Taking it a step further, you can likely do without an intermediate variable altogether.

I'm unable to test this since your question didn't include the definition of the custom type `clsDataRow`, nor any sample data, but basically you could do something like this:

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 0

Public Headers() As clsDataRow

Sub CreateTemplate()
    Dim iLastRow As Integer, iHeaderCount As Integer, Counter As Integer
    With shtsetup.Range("rngTemplate")
        iLastRow=shtsetup.Cells(Rows.Count,"A").End(xlUp).Row 'get last row#
        iHeaderCount = iLastRow - .Row                        'count headers
        ReDim Headers(iHeaderCount)                           'init array
        For Counter = 0 To iHeaderCount                       'populate headers()
            Headers(Counter).Name = .Offset(Counter, 0)
            Headers(Counter).Number = .Offset(Counter, 1)
            Headers(Counter).PDFFieldName = .Offset(Counter, 2)
            Headers(Counter).MinCharLimit = .Offset(Counter, 3)
            Headers(Counter).MaxCharLimit = .Offset(Counter, 4)
        Next Counter
    End With
End Sub
```

- I also switched around the `With` statement because you were only referring to it once; this way is more efficient because you use it several times.
- You don't need to specify `.Value` since that's the default property returned from a cell.
- Your `+1` and `-1`'s were balancing each other out so I removed them.
- Two unnecessary variables were eliminated.

As i stated this may or may not work as-is; impossible to tell since I'm making assumptions about the missing information.

Comment: Thanks for the great tip. Your code should work as - is because all the data I have is 5 rows of texts. I still get the same error when Counter is 0. It refuses to assign the value.